# angular ng-repeat filter array by key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following data:

```
$scope.allNames = [
    "A": [ { "name": "a1" }, { "name": "a2" }, { "name": "a3"} ],
    "B": [ { "name": "b1" }, { "name": "b2" }, { "name": "b3"} ],
    "C": [ { "name": "c1" }, { "name": "c2" }, { "name": "c3"} ],
]

<div ng-repeat="(letter, names) in allNames | filter:myFilter">
    <h4>{{ letter }}</h4>
    <ul ng-repeat="n in names">
        <li>{{ n.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

// on click show only name for this letter.
<span ng-click="myFilter = ??">A</span>
<span ng-click="myFilter = ??">B</span>
<span ng-click="myFilter = ??">C</span>
```

What I'm trying to do is on click of `<span>A</span>` show only names that have `$key: A` in `allNames` variable or that start with ***A***. This is where I get stuck on how to filter by index of array.

Comment: You're missing some pretty important contextual information: `name1` thru `name9` values and `myFilter`.

Comment: A,B,C are Arrays Not object

Comment: your filter is on the wrong `ng-repeat`.  it should be on the element you want to filter, not the element you are choosing from.  also, putting an `ng-repeat` on a `ul` causes unusual UI glitches, the repeat should be on the `li` instead.

Comment: `$scope.allNames = {
    "A": [ { name: a1 }, { name: a2 }, { name: a3} ],
    "B": [ { name: b1 }, { name: b2 }, { name: b3} ],
    "C": [ { name: c1 }, { name: c2 }, { name: c3} ],
}` This is also wring values wire like `[
    {
        "name": "a1"
    },
    {
        "name": "a2"
    },
    {
        "name": "a3"
    }
]`

Comment: Thank you for correction, but this array is simply a dummy. I did not put much thought into it as I did not see it too relevant. Actual array is retrieved via `$http.get` to `$scope.allNames`, so its syntax is correct in my app. What I do not know is how to make a filter so that `ng-repeat` filtered by array key. I'm very new to angular I'm just starting learning it.

Comment: Do you need to use filter? Can you not just select that specific array using the desired key. `ng-click="chosenArray = allNames['A']"` then loop through `chosenArray` to display it's values?

Comment: yep, that's an option. I will try it right now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this it might be your solution - http://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/vsvxqnq7/4/

After clicking on A, B, C respective array is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.myFilter = '';
         $scope.allNames = {
             "A": ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
             "B": ['name4', 'name5', 'name6'],
             "C": ['name7', 'name8', 'name9']
         };

         $scope.change = function(key) {
             $scope.myFilter = key;
         };

     }]);
```

HTML -

```
     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in allNames" ng-show="myFilter == key">
         <h4>{{ key }}</h4>

        <ul ng-repeat="name in value">
            <li>{{ name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in allNames" ng-click="change(key)">                 
        {{key}}
    </div>
```